# Cannot retrieve Data from Twitter (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter

I am trying to create a web page that, when a user searches for a topic, shows the tweets in a certain city that relate to that topic. The request is going to Twitter successfully - the response is 200 and I can see the response data in the chrome developer tool. However, I can't get the data to post on my page, or even log in the console. I'm wondering if I'm calling it incorrectly? I'm specifically looking at this function:

```
// Function that appends search result to DOM
var formatTweet = function(tweets) {

  //console.log(tweets);

  // clone template
  var result = $('.topic-template .topic-results').clone();

  // console.log(result); // ?? not logging result

  var image = result.find('.profile-img');
  image.attr('src', tweets.profile_image_url);

  var status = result.find('.status');
  status.append(tweets.text);

  var screenName = result.find('.screen-name');
  screenName.append(tweets.statuses.user.screen_name);

  var location = result.find('location');
  location.append(tweets.user.location);

  var time = result.find('.time');
  time.append(tweets.created_at); 

  return result; 
}; // end showUser function
```

Maybe I'm references the tweets objects incorrectly? I am getting an error that says: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'screen_name' of undefined.`

There is also an error that says:

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
Stack trace: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
    at Object.AMZUWLXT.tests.popNodeData (chrome-extension://ciagpekplgpbepdgggflgmahnjgiaced/contentScripts/tests.js:79:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://ciagpekplgpbepdgggflgmahnjgiaced/contentScripts/tests.js:168:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://ciagpekplgpbepdgggflgmahnjgiaced/contentScripts/tests.js:12:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://ciagpekplgpbepdgggflgmahnjgiaced/contentScripts/tests.js:12:28)
    at chrome-extension://ciagpekplgpbepdgggflgmahnjgiaced/contentScripts/tests.js:12:28
    at Object.runPage (chrome-extension://ciagpekplgpbepdgggflgmahnjgiaced/contentScripts/isProduct.js:159:12)
    at chrome-extension://ciagpekplgpbepdgggflgmahnjgiaced/contentScripts/runIsProduct.js:15:22
    at messageListener (extensions::messaging:340:9)
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at EventImpl.dispatchToListener (extensions::event_bindings:395:22)
```

I have no idea what this means.

I'm not sure how to debug.

Here is the link: http://amykirst.github.io/twitter-api/

Comment: `console.log(tweets);` PS: you have exactly 0 (zero) lines relevant to AJAX in the code you provided, not sure why you even mentioned it.

Comment: "or even log in the console" --- it means that `console.log` was not invoked. What it means - is that whole this function wasn't called.

Comment: I tried console.log(tweets) but it didn't work. It's commented out in my code. It didn't log anything. My ajax code is in the github, I didn't know if it was the problem or not - I'm assuming not because the request is successful, which is why I didn't copy and paste it here.

Comment: if it wasn't invoked - then you didn't invoke this function. `console.log` **ALWAYS** outputs something (unless you overrode it, which would be kinda weird)

Comment: Just tested it again. console.log(tweets) works. It's the console.log(result) that doesn't work, which is why I posted that part of the code. There must be a problem with it, but I don't know what.

Comment: "but I don't know what" --- it's clearly explained in the error message: "Cannot read property 'screen_name' of undefined."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the GET request you did, you get all the related statuses as a tweet objects as response.

Below is what you get after your first api call to twitter.

```
Statuses

    0 Object { metadata={...}, created_at="Thu Jul 10 02:08:11 +0000 2014", id=487055653404672000, more...}
    1 Object { metadata={...}, created_at="Wed Jul 09 22:32:23 +0000 2014", id=487001346227175400, more...}
    2 Object { metadata={...}, created_at="Wed Jul 09 22:06:00 +0000 2014", id=486994705406648300, more...}     
    3 Object { metadata={...}, created_at="Wed Jul 09 21:58:41 +0000 2014", id=486992863012454400, more...}
    ...
    ...
```

After getting them all, you should iterate each and then format them.

In other words, in your function, you should be formatting only one object, a tweet.

If you check the properties of the response you will see that, for instance, the first object has properties like this :

```
0   
  contributors  null
  coordinates   null
  created_at    "Thu Jul 10 02:08:11 +0000 2014"
  entities      Object { hashtags=[0], symbols=[0], urls=[1], more...}
  favorite_count 0
  favorited     false
  ....
  ....
  text          "Game of Thrones Season I... http://t.co/y5gf52xXg5"
  user           Object { id=49376425, id_str="49376425", name="Mark Yesilevskiy", more...}
```

And you can see that the user property is an object within. So for instance if you want to access first object's user name property, then you can access it like from root as `Statuses[0].user.name`

So if we come to your problem, in an object, you can't access to `screen_name` parameter like yours, this is why you are getting that error.

To fix it, firstly after getting all the tweets successfully, iterate each and then format them.

```
$.each(tweets.statuses, function(i, tweet) {
     formatTweet(tweet).appendTo('#topic-results');
});​
```

And within your formatTweet function, you need to change this as i explained above:

```
screenName.append(tweets.statuses.user.screen_name);
```

To:

```
screenName.append(tweets.user.screen_name);
```

Also, you are actually accessing one tweet there, so it should be a `tweet` not `tweets` in logical, but it's not a problem as its just a parameter.

Also this is wrong too:

```
var location = result.find('location');
```

Change to:

```
var location = result.find('.location');
```

Plus, add this div to your html, where tweets will be appended:

```
<div id="topic-results"></div>
```

Here is a quick **fiddle** that you can check: http://jsfiddle.net/zeZ38/

Comment: Thank you. I believe I made your changes, but when I run it, with a console.log(tweets), it says that tweets is undefined. But we're cycling through the tweets object, so wouldn't it already be defined?

Comment: it should be, can you post your latest codes(all of them) to pastebin or to github?

Comment: in your get tweets function, within the done, change search to tweets: `.done(function(tweets) {`

Comment: @amylynn83 left any problems?

Comment: I got it. There were a few issues with my code...the biggest one being that I was deleting my template and then trying to put stuff in it. :) Thank you for your help!